# Android orientation in phonegap build?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, screen-orientation

Is there anyway to declare this piece of code in config.xml (the android.manifest does not exist in phonegap build):

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activity.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I want to force landscape at all times in my app, and the other declarations dont seem to work...any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@totothegreat,
You may recall this from a previous post:

> Lastly, if you want to implement this with config.xml, then I suggest
>   you [read the thread with Ben Jones' implementation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/phonegap/ben$20jones/phonegap/UdXbU8a-UKk/SAZg9F3YyzoJ). Best of luck, text
>   me back, if you are still having problems.

Is there something that is not clear in this post? Something that needs explaining?

Jesse

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following line in your config.xml :

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
```

[Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File)

Comment: This one is not working at all, when i enter my app, this config is ignored, it still shows a seconds or 2 of my app in portrait and then it fixes itself, this is not a good thing

Comment: your cordova version?

Comment: 3.7.0 seems like the latest isn't it?